# iPhone: Indexpath.row of UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, uicollectionview, nsindexpath

I try to remake the image gallery of iOS.

In the detail screen of an image i want to update the title of the navigationbar to like

```
3 of 19
```

Is there a way to get the current **indexpath.row** of the visible object and next to that update the image title when the **UICollectionView** stopped scrolling and update the '3 of 19' title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works fine!

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didEndDisplayingCell:(UICollectionViewCell *)cell forItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    BOPhotoCollectionViewCell* currentCell = ([[collectionView visibleCells]count] > 0) ? [[collectionView visibleCells] objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    if(cell != nil){
        _index = [collectionView indexPathForCell:currentCell].row;
        [self updateTitle];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Implement below delegate method of UIScrollViewDelegate(as UICollectionViewDelegate is inherited from UIScrollViewDelegate).

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  NSInteger currentIndex = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;
  [self setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld of %ld",(long)currentIndex + 1, (long)self.itemList.count]]; 
}
```